# How to model people and companies with single table inheritance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

In my Invoicing app `invoices` can be sent to either a `company` or a `person`. As I understand it, this is a good use case for Rails' single table inheritance (STI). Since both types share a number of attributes and functions, I figured that a super-class `Recipient` might be a good way to go:

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base 
end

class Company < Recipient
  has_many :people
end

class Person < Recipient
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I also understand that I need an attribute `type` in the `Recipient` model.

The only thing that bothers me is the fact that a `person` may (or may not) belong to a `company`. How can this be modelled in Rails? Normally, I'd simply add another database field `company_id` to the `people` table. But there's only one table (`recipients`) here. So how can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is Concerns for making a Company and a Person separate models entirely, and including a concern called (for example) Billable or Invoicable or along those lines, for keeping the invoice-logic. However STI is also an excellent usecase here. Let me write up an answer in a second, for the STI-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure could look like this:

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :invoices
end

class Company < Recipient
  has_many :people
end

class Person < Recipient
  belongs_to :company
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipients
end

# Schema
create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "recipient_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["recipient_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_recipient_id"
end

create_table "recipients", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "company_id"
  t.string "type"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I've just tried in the console:

```
> Recipient.all
 => [#<Company:0x007fd55d797220
  id: 1,
  company_id: nil,
  type: "Company",
  created_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Person:0x007fd55d796730
  id: 2,
  company_id: 1,
  type: "Person",
  created_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Person:0x007fd55d796208
  id: 3,
  company_id: nil,
  type: "Person",
  created_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 10:57:41 UTC +00:00>]

> Person.last.company
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipients".* FROM "recipients" WHERE "recipients"."type" IN ('Person') ORDER BY "recipients"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil

> Person.first.company
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipients".* FROM "recipients" WHERE "recipients"."type" IN ('Person') ORDER BY "recipients"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipients".* FROM "recipients" WHERE "recipients"."type" IN ('Company') AND "recipients"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Company id: 1, company_id: nil, type: "Company", created_at: "2017-08-04 10:57:41", updated_at: "2017-08-04 10:57:41">
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I had in mind. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @Tintin81 Great! Anything else you need? Or could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base 
end

class Company < Recipient
  has_many :people, class_name: "Recipient", foreign_key: 'parent_id' 
end

class Person < Recipient
  belongs_to :company, class_name: "Recipient", foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

Just add `parent_id`  to recipient migration.
And that is it simple and fast and you get what you want one model two STI and `has_many` and `belongs_to` between `company` and `person`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is `class_name: "Recipient"` strictly necessary to get this to work?

Comment: @Tintin81 no you don`t but I like to use it more info better :)

Comment: Thanks, I took the liberty to mark Frederik's answer as the correct one because he went a bit more into detail, but I might as well have marked yours. You both helped me a lot here.